# Pivot table options not working in powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm still new to powershell but have been working with the ImportExcel module and have some questions.

I'm doing the following and it is working

```
Import-Csv C:\path | Export-Excel C:\path -Show -IncludePivotTable
```

So then when I try to define the rows for the pivot table using the following

```
Import-Csv C:\path | Export-Excel C:\path -Show -IncludePivotTable -PivotRows "row_Name"
```

I get the following errors

**Export-Excel : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:55
+ ... _xxxxx.csv | Export-Excel C:\path -Show -PivotR ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{Customer=xxxx...ent ID=xxxxxx}:PSObject) [Export-Excel], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Export-Excel**

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

-Dustin

Comment: You could use `Trace-Command` to inspect why input is being bound differently when you add the `-PivotRows` parameter. Also, please update your question with *the exact* command line you used, according to the error output you've place `-PivotRows` immediately after `-Show` in the failing example

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, where do you add the Trace-Command, before everything or after?